# FlashDevelop cannot see the MXML Component File I made

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, mxml

Following a Video tutorial on Flex, but I am inside the FlashDevelop IDE as opposed to Flex Builder.

Now, in the video they create a custom MXML Component which is simply a derived Horizontal Box.

The markup of the video tutorial to mine is the same and I have the MXML file in the same folder as the Main.MXML.  I get the following build error:

> C:\Flex\TwitterApp\src\TwitterApp\Main.mxml(30):  Error: Definition Tweet could not be found.
>   dataProvider="{ac}" itemRenderer="Tweet">
>   Build halted with errors (fcsh).

Everything else works fine, but I would like to know how to inform FlashDevelop of the MXML Component.

The source file on the Video does not reference the MXML file inside the Main.MXML at all, but i am aware that something is probably done behind the scenes in Flex Builder.

It is this I need to emulate inside FlashDevelop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not inluded the folder in my classpaths.  So it was not reconizing the file at compile time because it could not see it.  Adding the path to the class paths solved it! :-)